# Is it possible to beat 40,000 points in UNIKONG?

Tags: discussion, unikong

Asking for a friend. Finished the game and came nowhere near 40K.

[image]

Comment: 40K must be John Skeet's score

Comment: It does take time to earn a high score. Keep going!

Comment: `var konamiArray = [Phaser.Keyboard.UP, Phaser.Keyboard.UP, Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN, Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN, Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT, Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT, Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT, Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT, Phaser.Keyboard.B, Phaser.Keyboard.A, Phaser.Keyboard.ENTER]`

Comment: @j08691: What does it do? Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Bergi - So far all I've noticed are a shower or sparks

Comment: Went upto [24k](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYzF.png) and then got an [error](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320196/unikong-environment-halts-when-pressing-left-alt-key/320199#comment328858_320199) ...

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4767516#4767516

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. But you'll have to master your platformer skills to do it!

When you complete the level, choose CONTINUE to keep going!

Answer (score 11):

Winning for the truely lazy:

```
p='stackoverflow-unikong-leader-board';a=JSON.parse(localStorage[p]);a.pop();a.splice(0,0,{initials:'YOU',score:100000});localStorage[p]=JSON.stringify(a);
```

Just punch the 1-liner into your developer console, and done.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, [by doing this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277734/203888).

Sure, you can keep going with "Continue", but as long as you dodge the occasional fireball-downvote, you can stay on Level 3 for a long time.

Comment: Not anymore you can't!

Comment: @Haney Thanks for fixing that bug!  That pretty much guarantees I have the best all-time Unikong reputation score!

Comment: @rgettman given that the javascript console exists: I doubt that

Comment: @MarcGravell http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4767516#4767516 minutes after it went live

Comment: @Quill remember: real developers play games by pressing ctrl+shift+j; all listed inputs are for "users".

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have, but if I open stackoverflow in another browser (where I am not authenticated), I still see 40000 at the top (my results are not added there, at least until now).

[image: my score]

Comment: That score must have been a bug.