# Unikong environment halts when pressing left alt key

Tags: bug, unikong

The entire gaming environment, even the home menu screen, halts when pressing the <kbd>left alt</kbd> key. But <kbd>P</kbd> is the key officially stated for pausing the game. That too not for halting the menu screen. Is it a bug or a feature?

I am checking with the latest Chrome, version 49.0.2623.110 m.

Comment: Think of it as an alt-ending.

Comment: Chill out with the excess fun, everyone. Comments should be posted as comments, not answers!

Comment: Another potential bug: I noticed the "current rep" display between ads doesn't reflect the same number as on my StackOverflow profile page.

Comment: @CubeJockey: `Syntax Error: type 'fun' cannot be qualified by 'excess' outside 'Humbug' context`

Answer (score 36):

Don't press the left <kbd>alt</kbd> key, and you have no problem.

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Hackenbush!

Comment: How do you resume after you pause? It is struck like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/vUYzF.png from 10 mins :-(

Comment: @BhargavRao that seems like a bug. See if you can reproduce or errors in console?

Comment: This is the console .... http://i.stack.imgur.com/BfWPK.png, I closed the console and the game stopped. Now I have only "New Game" option.

Comment: :O I didn't even notice the gun shot RAINBOWS!!!!!

Answer (score 18):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key sets the focus on the Chrome menu icon in the top right, which in turn tells the game that the window has been unfocused and thus pauses rendering (to save resources, I assume).

Answer (score 7):

Prise off the keytop and glue on a thumbtack instead, point-up.

Comment: Just sayin'... https://twitter.com/marcgravell/status/571019036072542208 (and yes: it still looks like that today)